# Failed executing DbCommand. .NET CORE

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

During creating my first page I noticed that I could not run .Net from cmd. I do not know what exactly is a problem. I am sending you a command lines.

I checked some website's solutions. None from this solutions helped me.

C:\Users\prywatny\Desktop\ProjektodZera\BigProject\BigProject>dotnet ef database update
Done.

C:\Users\prywatny\Desktop\ProjektodZera\BigProject\BigProject>dotnet run
Używanie ustawień uruchamiania z profilu C:\Users\prywatny\Desktop\ProjektodZera\BigProject\BigProject\Properties\launchSettings.json...

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (133ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedEmail_0='?' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id], [u].[AccessFailedCount], [u].[ConcurrencyStamp], [u].[Email], [u].[EmailConfirmed], [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName], [u].[LockoutEnabled], [u].[LockoutEnd], [u].[NormalizedEmail], [u].[NormalizedUserName], [u].[PasswordHash], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [u].[SecurityStamp], [u].[TwoFactorEnabled], [u].[UserName]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u]
      WHERE [u].[NormalizedEmail] = @__normalizedEmail_0
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:68090395-2d00-4ce7-9f2b-0ed6813b9694
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'BigProject.Data.Context'.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 para
Unhandled Exception: meterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault_[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      ClientConnectionId:68090395-2d00-4ce7-9f2b-0ed6813b9694
      Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault_[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:68090395-2d00-4ce7-9f2b-0ed6813b9694
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.) ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault_[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByEmailAsync(String email)
   at BigProject.Data.Seeder.SeedAsync() in C:\Users\prywatny\Desktop\ProjektodZera\BigProject\BigProject\Data\Seeder.cs:line 32
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at BigProject.Program.SeedDb(IWebHost host) in C:\Users\prywatny\Desktop\ProjektodZera\BigProject\BigProject\Program.cs:line 32
   at BigProject.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\prywatny\Desktop\ProjektodZera\BigProject\BigProject\Program.cs:line 22
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'BigProject.Data.Context'.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault_[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
      ClientConnectionId:68090395-2d00-4ce7-9f2b-0ed6813b9694
      Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault_[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
ClientConnectionId:68090395-2d00-4ce7-9f2b-0ed6813b9694
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
```

C:\Users\prywatny\Desktop\ProjektodZera\BigProject\BigProject>

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'`

Answer (score 4):

The error is quite clear at the top of the stack trace you posted, although these big error messages can be hard to read sometimes:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (133ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedEmail_0='?' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id], [u].[AccessFailedCount], [u].[ConcurrencyStamp], [u].[Email], [u].[EmailConfirmed], [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName], [u].[LockoutEnabled], [u].[LockoutEnd], [u].[NormalizedEmail], [u].[NormalizedUserName], [u].[PasswordHash], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [u].[SecurityStamp], [u].[TwoFactorEnabled], [u].[UserName]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u]
      WHERE [u].[NormalizedEmail] = @__normalizedEmail_0
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
```

So the system is trying to run the query:

```
 SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Id], [u].[AccessFailedCount], [u].[ConcurrencyStamp], [u].[Email], [u].[EmailConfirmed], [u].[FirstName], [u].[LastName], [u].[LockoutEnabled], [u].[LockoutEnd], [u].[NormalizedEmail], [u].[NormalizedUserName], [u].[PasswordHash], [u].[PhoneNumber], [u].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [u].[SecurityStamp], [u].[TwoFactorEnabled], [u].[UserName]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [u]
      WHERE [u].[NormalizedEmail] = @__normalizedEmail_0
```

And is getting the error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.
```

You should check that the table exists and that the user account you are using has access to the table. You could even try running the query yourself from SQL Management Studio to see what happens

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but still i really do not know what to do

Comment: @Drax - Your query is attempting to access a table called "AspNetUsers" which doesn't seem to exist.  Are you sure the connection string is pointing to a database that has a table with that name?  Perhaps your entity for that table is not correct.  It's difficult to say since you did not provide any code.

Comment: I came through the same issue, In my case i deleted the Snapshot File that gets auto generated while creating the Migration . It resolved my issue

Comment: I also got a `Failed executing DbCommand`, yet the SQL command itself was fine.  I finally resolved it by comparing every change since the last commit and finding `<Nullable>annotations</Nullable>` had appeared in the .csproj file in the top `<PropertyGroup>`.  Removing this line fixed the problem.  Why? Where did it come from?  No idea.